# Symfony 5.2 select2 How to loading saved entities to select2 relationship Many to Many

Tags: php, symfony, entity, symfony5

I have two entities CustomSupplier, BlockedPn  With ManyToMany relationship.
I am using select2 for choose values from CustomSupplier entity.

When I save or remove values from $suppliers it works fine.

But I have some problem with selected saved values in detail.
Selected values are not loading to select input.

I tried different settings in FormType but nothing helped.

must I load the selected values manually? Or?

Entity BlockedPn.php

```
    class BlockedPn
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=CustomSupplier::class, inversedBy="blockedPns")
         */
        private $suppliers;
    
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->suppliers = new ArrayCollection();
        }
    
        /**
         * @return Collection|CustomSupplier[]
         */
        public function getSuppliers(): Collection
        {
            return $this->suppliers;
        }
    
        public function addSuppliers(CustomSupplier $supplier): self
        {
            if (!$this->suppliers->contains($supplier)) {
                $this->suppliers[] = $supplier;
            }
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        /**
         * @param mixed $suppliers
         */
        public function setSuppliers($suppliers)
        {
            $this->suppliers = $suppliers;
        }
    ...
    }
    
    
    Entity CustomSupplier.php
    
    class CustomSupplier
    {
    
    /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=BlockedPn::class, mappedBy="suppliers")
         */
        private $blockedPns;
    
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->blockedPns = new ArrayCollection();
        }
    
        /**
         * @return Collection|CustomSupplier[]
         */
        public function getBlockedPns(): Collection
        {
            return $this->blockedPns;
        }

    /**
     * @param $pn
     */
    public function addBlockedPns($pn)
    {
        $this->blockedPns[] = $pn;
    }
}
```

My FormType with EntityType with multiple option.

```
class BlockedPnType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add("pn",null,[
                'label' => 'Part Number'
            ])
            ->add("suppliers",EntityType::class,[
                'class' => CustomSupplier::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'choice_value' => 'id',
                'multiple' => true,
                'mapped' => true,
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('b')->orderBy('b.name', 'ASC');
                }
}
}
```

Controller action for detail:

```
/**
 * @Route ("/blocked-pn/detail/{id}",name="block_pns_detail")
 */
public function blockPnsDetail(int $id, Request $request)
{
    $blockedPn = $this->em->getRepository(BlockedPn::class)
                          ->find($id);
    

    $form = $this->createForm(BlockedPnType::class, $blockedPn);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
    {
        $this->addFlash('success','Part number edited');

        $this->em->persist($blockedPn);
        $this->em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('block_pns_detail',['id' => $blockedPn->getId()]);
    }


    return $this->render('blocked_pns/new.html.twig',['form' => $form->createView()]);
}
```

And from template .twig

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#blocked_pn_suppliers').select2();
    });
</script>


                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
                                    <label for="term_name">{{ form_label(form.suppliers) }}</label>
                                        {{ form_widget(form.suppliers) }}
                                    <div class="text-danger">{{ form_errors(form.suppliers) }}</div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
```